# Prevent some BGP prefixes from entering the RIB

Tags: bgp, bgp-ipv6, route-filter

I would like to know if it's possible to prevent some BGP prefixes from entering the RIB.

I'm receiving full internet routes from 2 ISPs, and I'm getting duplicate paths in BGP table, but only the best goes to the RIB.
However, my routers have a limitation on the number of routes allowed in the RIB, and I would like to prevent some BGP routes from entering the RIB (more specifically, the ones that are tied, so that the router just uses the default route).

I know all kind of filtering can be done to prevent routes from entering the BGP table, but is it possible to use route-maps to do what I want? Where would I apply them? Thanks!

Comment: I know the redistribute commands on Cisco CLI, there you can "put" routes from bgp to rip, shouldn't be much different on different IOS.
Also a part of your configuration and what device you use would be helpful.

Comment: When you redistribute between 2 routing protocols you can always filter using a route-map. But you never redistribute from the BGP table to the RIB, and you don't even enter a command for that, the best routes are simply installed automatically.
What I am trying to know is if there s any way of filtering these best routes, the way I would do in a redistribution.

Note: These devices are Brocade, which configurations are very Cisco-like.

Comment: Ok, forget the retribution, read RIP not RIB. One thing i can think of is using the neighbor command.
example:
neighbor {ip-address| peer-group-name} remote-as autonomous-system-number 

neighbor {ip-address| peer-group-name} route-map map-name {in | out} 
and configure your route map for the ip adresses you want to route.

Comment: [cisco site link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13750-22.html)
Uses the distribute command in the router bgp config. Try this.

Comment: Hope you also have a default route if you do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.
It is possible to filter BGP routes from entering the RIB. You just have to use the *table-map* command to filter using a route-map.
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_bgp/configuration/xe-3s/irg-xe-3s-book/bgp-selective_route_download.pdf

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may filter same way as you would filter bogon networks with prefix lists.
For example:

```
ip prefix-list rfc1918 deny 10.0.0.0/8 le 32

router bgp xxx
 neighbor x.x.x.x prefix-list rfc1918 in
```

But routers with full BGP feeds should avoid default routes.

Other ways to filter incoming prefixes is to use distribute lists with access-lists.

Comment: Thank you, but you missed the point. You are still filtering BGP prefixes from entering BGP table. I want to allow all prefixes INTO the BGP table, from both ISPs. I then want to filter WHAT GOES INTO the RIB. Assuming that is possible.